# Is it true that all of the euclidean geometry problem in the IMO(international mathematical olympiad) could all be solve by the analytical geometry?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Is it true that all of the euclidean geometry problem in the IMO(international mathematical olympiad) or even generalize to say that all the plane geometry problem  and 3d-geometry could be solve by the analytical geometry/algebraic geometry?

Comment: I have not gone through all of them. For sure almost all of the standard high level hideous geometric problems could in principle be. The proofs would be mechanical but not necessarily pleasant. This is an old result of Tarski.

Comment: "(without the ability to measure angles)"!

Comment: @ABC - 
We could use trignometric function...

Comment: If you solve trigonometric equations Tarski's result is no longer applicable.

Comment: But problems that mention angles with a specific number of integer degrees easily fall under the Tarski rubric. What we must avoid is talking about general integers.

Comment: Indeed. I think there are problems about $n$-gons, with $n$ an unknown of the problem that are not decidable. I remember a problem in a Chinese national olympiad that was about $n,m,k$-gons constructed on the sides of a triangle such that something happened. I wonder if some family of generalizations of it would be undecidable. It was a pretty hard problem to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By an [old result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) of Tarski, the elementary theory of real-closed fields is decidable. A great many problems in elementary geometry, including the typical IMO geometry problems, can be stated, via coordinatization, as sentences in the language of real-closed fields.

Tarski's general decision procedure can therefore be in principle applied to solve such problems.

There has been a certain amount of theoretical and practical implementation work done on the problem. Seidenberg and Cohen gave alternate approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the Chinese teams to the IMO were trained in the use of the "area method", which is a simplified form of (complex number) quantifier elimination adapted to plane geometry, developed and popularized in China, and implemented in geometric theorem-proving software.   The generality of the method is limited compared to full quantifier elimination, but it can handle any geometry problem where the configuration is constructible from a finite set of starting points by ruler and compass.   For theorems that require more complicated constructions or need the coordinates to be real (so as to have order properties such as two sides to every line) the area method can still be of some use but will not solve the problem completely by itself.

An earlier and more general technique, not suitable for hand calculation but implemented as theorem proving software, is Wu's method, which in computer algebra terms is "ideal membership testing" using Groebner bases.   It tests whether the equations defining the diagram in the statement of a geometry theorem imply the equation that expresses the theorem's conclusion.

If you have a full quantifier elimination engine (over $\mathbb{R}$) then any Euclidean geometry problem based on a finite number of points, lines, circles and straight-line distances, can be solved automatically.  This is the Tarski theorem and was part of his work on axiomatization of first-order Euclidean geometry.

Comment: You seem to be quite knowledgeable about the Chinese MO contestants and as you are divulging their secret let me ask you a question. :) Were you a contestant or a leader?

Comment: The information was published in Chou et al's book on geometric theorem proving using the area method.  Zhang, the originator of the method, wrote books explaining it to high school teachers, since in some sense it is a simplification of Euclidean geometry to the part that holds with complex coordinates.

Comment: Can you provide more details on these books. I would be obliged if you inform me the names of the books. Even the names of the sources would suffice.

Comment: Chou, Gao, Zhang *Machine Proofs In Geometry*.

Comment: (if you meant the books for high school teachers, they are listed in the bibliography of C-G-Z)