# Is it theotically possible to create a machine that could randomly generate any elementary geometric problems/theorem?

Tags: geometry

Refering back to this quesion: [Is it true that all of the euclidean geometry problem in the IMO(international mathematical olympiad) could all be solve by the analytical geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566197/is-it-true-that-all-of-the-euclidean-geometry-problem-in-the-imointernational-m) , we know that any elemetary geometry problem could be solved by computer in finite amount of time.

So, conversely, is it theotically possible to create a machine that could randomly generate any elementary geometric problems/theorem?

Comment: Have you studied the infinite monkey theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we formalize elementary geometry, say the plane version, using say Tarski's formalization (there are others).  Then of course we can generate all well-formed **sentences**.  As to the "randomly" part, we could use a pseudo-random number generator. If that is not good enough, I have no algorithmic suggestion.

Note that the axioms of Tarski's geometry are a recursive set. Therefore, as noted in the answer by apt1002, we can not only algorithmically list all sentences, we can algorithmically list all proofs. (A proof is just a special kind of finite list of sentences.)

Tarski's theory is **complete.** Therefore, in principle, to verify whether a sentence $\phi$ is a theorem, we just list all proofs. If $\phi$ appears at the end of a proof, then $\varphi$ is a theorem. If $\lnot\varphi$ appears at the end of a proof, then $\varphi$ is not a theorem. This procedure must terminare, so we have an algorithm.

Of course it is a terrible algorithm. Tarski's algorithm for the theory of real-closed fields, and the various implementations since, are far more efficient.

Comment: What is sentences you are speaking of?

Comment: The special symbols of the language are a $3$-ary predicate symbol to denote betweenness, and a binary predicate symbol to denote congruence. In addition, there are the usual logical symbols, that is, $=$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\lnot$, $\implies$, the two quantifiers, and infinitely many variable symbols $x_1,x_2,\dots$. The rules of sentence formation are the usual ones of first-order logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Proofs are ennumerable by a computer.

Comment: Please, consider expanding your answer -- explain, give a citation, etc.

Comment: Proofs are just finite strings of symbols drawn from a finite alphabet. You can write a program to list all finite strings. You can feed that output into another program that checks if the string is a proof. If so, you can make it print out the theorem. This process will theoretically eventually print any given theorem. If you modify the program to generate strings in a random order, it will print the theorems in a random order.

Comment: The question is "is it theotically possible to create a machine that could randomly generate any elementary geometric problems/theorem?". My answer is yes, and my method is as in my previous comment. What have I missed?